# Select Rows in DataBodyRange

Tags: excel, vba, windows, select, row

Trying to write VBA Excel code to select a row in my Data Table. Code I have is:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN_DATA").ListRows(3).DataBodyRange.Select
```

Also wanting to know how to select multiple rows from this Table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `ListRow` has `Range` but not `DataBodyRange`   You will need to explain a bit more around which specific multiple rows you want to select/reference.

Comment: Why do you want to `Select` rows anyway? Read [How to Avoid Using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

@Tim already answered your question in the comment.

I hope the sample is helpful for you to understand the syntax.

- The sample table named `MAIN_DATA`

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Sub Demo()
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("MAIN_DATA")
        Dim rRows As Range
        Debug.Print "[ListObject].Range: " & .Range.Address
        Debug.Print "[ListObject].DataBodyRange: " & .DataBodyRange.Address
        Debug.Print "[ListObject].ListRows(3).Range: " & .ListRows(3).Range.Address
        Debug.Print "[ListObject].DataBodyRange.Rows(3): " & .DataBodyRange.Rows(3).Address
        Set rRows = .ListRows(1).Range
        Set rRows = Union(rRows, .ListRows(3).Range)
        Debug.Print "1st and 3rd rows: " & rRows.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

*Output:*

```
[ListObject].Range: $A$1:$B$7
[ListObject].DataBodyRange: $A$2:$B$7
[ListObject].ListRows(3).Range: $A$4:$B$4
[ListObject].DataBodyRange.Rows(3): $A$4:$B$4
1st and 3rd rows: $A$2:$B$2,$A$4:$B$4
```